# Windows 7 register dll to Component Services by dragging files into the Components folder

Tags: windows-7

Prior to Win 7, I'm able to register dll by dragging the file into the "Components" folder of the application node I created. It no-longer works in Win 7. The reason I need this feature is that I'm registering over 400 dlls. Did Microsoft do away this feature or is it a bug? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

64 bit DLL:

```
 %windir%\system32\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\NeedRegistry.dll
```

32 bit DLL:

```
 %windir%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\SysWOW64\NeedRegistry.dll
```

Comment: Thanks. STTR. This only allows me to register 1 dll at a time. I would like to be able to drag and drop the dlls (400+ dlls). It works on WinServer 2008. It doesn't work on Win7.